# Finishing write stream in external module upon program error

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling, data-stream

**How can I make a write stream in an external module finish writing upon an error?**

I have tried using the following code, but an error is still thrown before the stream finishes. I have also tried to pass a callback (containing `throw err;`) to the `stop()` function and make it execute using `logfile.on('end', () => { callback(); })`, but that doesn't do anything.

*index.js*

```
process.on('uncaughtException', (err) => {
    logger.stop(); // function in external module
    throw err;
});
...
 Oh no! Waffles broke the code, because they're evil!
```

*logger.js*

```
module.exports = {
    ...
    stop: () => {
        logfile.end(); // logfile is a global variable containing a write stream
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem can be solved by displaying the error using `console.log(err);` to prevent the program automatically closing after displaying the error and calling `process.exit(1);` in the external module, when the `finish` event is called.

*index.js*

```
process.on('uncaughtException', (err) => {
    console.error(err);
    logger.stop();
});
...
 Oh no! Waffles broke the code, because they're evil!
```

*logger.js*

```
module.exports = {
    ...
    stop: () => {
        logfile.on('finish', () => { process.exit(1); });
        logfile.end();
    }
}
```